# I am getting following error while generating token from FCM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> Google.Apis.Http.Configurable MessageHandler.d__59.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

It is working fine with one server but not working with another  server

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
  //var buildDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
  string token = string.Empty;
  try
  {
    List<string> scope = new List<string>();
    scope.Add(firebaseMessagingURL); //Will Not Change --Until or unless changes by google 
    GoogleCredential googlCredentail = GoogleCredential.FromJson(firebasecredential).CreateScoped(scope);
    token = await googlCredentail.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
    return token;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logging.WriteLog(ex, Logging.LogMsgType.General, Logging.CacheStoresName.Empty.ToString());
  }
  return token;
}
```